# Modernizr динамически подгрузить / заменить select multiply

Tags: jquery

используется jquery c Modernizr 2.8.3 (Custom Build) | MIT & BSD
значения дергаются ajax-ом
и естественно в коллбеке
`$('#select').empty().append(html_code);`
не работает
где то описаны методы работы с селекторами библиотеки Modernizr ?